# Javascript Event Crosswiring

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For some reason when you mouse over either menu item, only the second one gets the color change. Code is below.

```
$(document).ready
   (
   function(){   
    var menuItems = [$("#calendar_menu_item"), $("#patient_menu_item")];
      
    for (i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
     var menuItem = menuItems[i];     
     
     menuItem.bind('mouseover', function(){
      menuItem = menuItems[i]; 
      menuItem.css("background-color", "#749ccf");
     });
     
     menuItem.bind('mouseout', function(){
      menuItem = menuItems[i]; 
      menuItem.css("background-color", "#506077");
     });
    }
   }
   );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails because `i` is changed after you use it in the internal function.  Whenever you do `i++`, it affects every reference to `i` in that scope **including in functions that extend that scope**.

The solution here is to use `this` instead.  `this`, within an event handler, is a reference to the event on which the event was triggered.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menuItems = [$("#calendar_menu_item"), $("#patient_menu_item")];

    for (i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        var menuItem = menuItems[i];

        menuItem.bind('mouseover', function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#749ccf");
        });

        menuItem.bind('mouseout', function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#506077");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lonesomeday. I come to javascript (by way of Java) and so some of the finer points are.....interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to iterate over them, you can assign to multiple  ID'd items at the same time, even mix ID and class if you want.

$(document).ready
   (function(){

```
 $("#calendar_menu_item,#patient_menu_item").bind('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "#749ccf");
 });

 $("#calendar_menu_item,#patient_menu_item").bind('mouseout', function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "#506077");
 });
});
```